# Broker queue attributes not displayed

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

We are using jconsole (Java 1.7) to perform jmx connection to activemq broker. The broker is running on an apache tomee (1.6) instance. We are able to connect using jconsole, but when we expand the broker to see the queues, we could not see the queue attributes (e.g. QueueSize). In fact, the queues configured are not displayed as endpoints. Rather, it's displayed as folders. PFA screenshot for more details.
![Broker Queue displayed as folders][1]

We are not quite sure why this issue is happening. We have verified the application server configuration for broker and queue setup and it looks fine. Please let me know if anyone has any idea regarding this issue.

Thanks
Aditya Aery

Comment: Activemq broker is configured like

brokerService.addConnector(Constants.BROKER_URL); brokerService.setBrokerName("AmqBrokerProvider"); brokerService.setDataDirectoryFile(datadirFile); brokerService.start();

Messages are flowing properly from one broker queue to another. If we clear the "activemq-data" folder of tomee instance every time we restart, then we can see the queue attributes in jconsole properly. But clearing the "activemq-data" folder on every restart will result in loss of messages which are already in broker queues are are yet to be processed. Anyone knows the reason, plz help.